# VB Excel 2010 Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

All I am trying to do is to get a cell to show the percentage increase/decrease between two other cells. The code works fine when there are numerical values in there but after pressing the reset' button (which sets the cell values to "-"), it wont work even though I have worked the "-" scenario into my code:

```
Private Sub PerChange(ByVal burn1 As Range, burn2 As Range, change As Range)

If burn1.Value And burn2.Value = "-" Then
    change.Value = "-"
Else
    change.Value = (burn1.Value / burn2.Value) - 1
End If

End Sub
```

It is the bold line where the error occurs even though the values of both are "-"

I also tried swapping the bold line for:

```
**If IsNumeric(burn1.value and burn2.value) = False**
```

and it still stopped with a TYpe mismatch on this line, even though the whole point of IsNumeric is to check for non numeric types!!

Please advise as I am tearing my hair out...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `burn1.Value = "-" And burn2.Value = "-"` ? Also `If IsNumeric(burn1.value and burn2.value) = False` is valid but definetly not what you want. Try `If Not IsNumeric(burn1.value) and Not IsNumeric(burn2.value)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can i Just ask though, you said my statement was valid but not waht I want. Why is that?  Is it because IsNumeric() can only take one value?

Comment: The thing is that `IsNumeric(burn1.value and burn2.value)` says that you want to know if the expression `burn1.value and burn2.value` is a numeric value. Using the `And` operator on variant values is error prone and not very intuitive, and definitely not what you are trying to achieve. For example, if one of the cell value is a string which cannot be converted to a number (ex. "abc"), you will get an error. Or if your cells are empty then `Empty and Empty` will actually return zero which is a numerical value. So yes, use `IsNumeric` on expression you can predict, like a single variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Private Sub PerChange(ByVal burn1 As Range, burn2 As Range, change As Range)
    If burn1.Text = "-" And burn2.Text = "-" Then
        change.Value = "-"
    Else
        change.Value = (burn1.Value / burn2.Value) - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

tested with:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call PerChange(Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("B1"))
End Sub
```